# Find words from a sequence of random letters?

Tags: java, javascript, python, algorithm, pi

I'm working on a project where I first translated the digits of 'pi' to english letters by assigning each number to a letter (a=0, b=1, etc). I converted 10,000 digits of Pi which gave me these [8700 letters](https://github.com/darshilvala/Pi_letters/commit/06f00cf4509ab0a5090093bbcc6511e323b6e47c) to work with. The second step involves finding meaningful words from this generated letter sequence. I was wondering if anyone has ever worked on such a project? Can somebody post an algorithm or a linear code that will help me easily find the words of the random sequence? If not the code directly, could anyone show me a workaround of an easier approach to finding the words?

[This link](http://www-personal.umich.edu/~jlawler/wordlist) has all the letters from an English dictionary listed for easier selection.

EDIT: I'm sorry I didnt mention how the code works. The java code takes two numbers into consideration and assigns it a character (eg. o=14) since letters after 9 wont be assigned. If the number is above 25, 2 and 5 are considered separately. For example, 2526 would be z(25), b(2) and g(6) since 26 is split into 2 & 6.

Comment: You might want to look at a trie (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie). Note that with only the letters a-j, you'll have a very limited set of words.

Comment: Stupid question probably, but how do you get 8700 letters from 10000 digits if every digit is a letter?

Comment: The brute force way would be to find the maximum word length, find all permutations of your sequence of all lengths starting from 2 to maxlength and find which of them exists. Fire it up and go to sleep

Comment: As this question is a request for an algorithm, it is unclear whether it is off topic:  http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261673/are-plz-send-teh-alogithmz-questions-off-topic-or-poor-quality

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a sufficiently small problem that bruteforce works in less than a second:

Python code:

```
for pi in open('pi.txt'):
    pi = pi.upper()
    words = [word.rstrip() for word in open('wordlist.txt') if word.rstrip().upper() in pi]
```

(pi.txt is a file containing your converted letters)

To print the words in length order you can use:

```
words.sort(key=len)
for word in words:
    print word
```

The longest words are:

```
high
jive
life
shah
facie
hutch
```

Comment: Thank you for your input!

I tried to input the directory where I'm supposed to [for pi in open('/Users/admin/Documents/Math/IB/EE/translatedvalues.rtf')] but the code exited with code 1

Comment: Did Python print out any error message?  (By the way the last 3 lines of your program should not be indented or you will print out the words each time round the list.)  Also check which python version you are using (via python --version)  I am using 2.7.5

Comment: I'm running the code on TextMate (Mac) and the support in it is up-to-date so no worries there and even checked it for the IDE and it is 2.7.5.

[This](http://miscpix.com/e6gt5) is the error message I received just to make it clear.

Can you leave a screeshot of wherever you highlighted the problem? You can use [tinypic.cc](http://miscpix.com/e6gt5) for uploads.

Comment: @user3575083 I've never heard of TextMate, but I wonder if it has actually worked and copied the output to the clipboard?  What happens if you press paste?  (Also I take back my comment about needing to unindent the lines - your code should be fine)

Comment: TextMate works as an IDE and it does work well even with codes of greater complexity. I'm sorry but I tried changing what you said but it didnt work. And the 'output copied to clipboard' part shows up with i press the 'copy to clipboard' button so that wont be affecting the output.

Comment: I'm sorry you've contributed plenty but there seems to be an error. If you dont mind, could add a reply with the code that has my local directory instead of the 'pi.txt'? That would be very helpful. I've put the random string of letters in /Users/admin/Documents/Math/IB/EE/translatedvalues.rtf and dictionary cross-reference file's in /Users/admin/Documents/Math/IB/EE/wordlist.txt

Thank you so much for your help again.

Comment: @user3575083 You seem to be missing the end of the line that says " in pi]"

Comment: I didnt get you. I'm sorry I'm fairly new to all of this.

Comment: @user3575083 All I meant is that it looks from your screenshot as if when you copied the code into your editor you missed off the end of the one of the lines which is why your program is not working.

Comment: @user3575083 Almost, looks like you are missing a space between upper() and pi

Comment: FINALLY! I got to run the code with an exit code #0 which according my knowledge means it passed all the requirements. One problem though, the 'print' script did not yield an output. I'm using TextMate as I mentioned and the output actually printed nothing. If there's a possible problem with the IDE, can you suggest me an alternative. For the macOS.

Comment: I dont mean to bother you any further but i think something's missing from the code. Like I said, I'm getting an exit code 0 (so no errors thankfully) but I see no 'printed output'. [This is what it looks like](https://github.com/darshilvala/Pi_letters/blob/master/Trie%20Algorithm). Can you suggest/improve/extend/correct this so that I can get an output just like you did earlier? Thanks a lot sire.

Comment: Check that translatedvalues.rtf contains just a single line of text with your letters of pi inside it. (Things may go wrong if it has blank lines at the end.)

Comment: Oh no no, the translatedvalues.rtf doc is [this one](https://github.com/darshilvala/Pi_letters/commit/06f00cf4509ab0a5090093bbcc6511e323b6e47c). I converted the values of pi to letters and stored that in translatedvalues.rtf

The wordlist.rtf has a list of words from a dictionary that the code will refer to and find meaningful words of the random letter sequence in translatedvalues.rtf

Comment: I checked for any blank lines in the document and everything is fine. I also checked whether it is in a single line and it is.